# Python Generate dummy in dataframe based on another variable(pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dummy-variable

I have dataframe with many variables. I would like to generate a dummy variable based on column 1, for example. If column 1's observation is more than 0.25 then the dummy variable is filled with 1. If column 1' observation is less than 0.25, then the dummy variable is filled with 0. Any ideas? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC compare values for greater like `0.25` and then cast to integers for map `True/False` to `1/0`:

```
df[1] = df[1].gt(0.25).astype(int)
```

If first column:

```
df.iloc[:, 0] = df.iloc[:, 0].gt(0.25).astype(int)
```

Comment: how can I add this dummy variable to my dataframe? I used 'df[dummy]=df[1].gt(0.25).astype(int)'                                but it didnt work

Comment: @MarziehKarimi - Added to answer, if need new column use instead `df[1] = ` or `df.iloc[:, 0] = ` this - `df['dummy1'] = `

Comment: I used the first code but I received this error :   ('<ipython-input-86-7f424b93050c>:1: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead')

Comment: @MarziehKarimi - Can you show your complete code in question? also 5 rows of code before is raised errro.

Comment: @MarziehKarimi - I think by [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69852332/edit)

Comment: `df[1] = df[1].gt(0.25).astype(int)`

Comment: @MarziehKarimi - There is some filtration before `df[1] = df[1].gt(0.25).astype(int)` ? How is created `df` ?

Comment: `df=df1[['CLOSDATE_year','LCR','WFR']]`

Comment: @MarziehKarimi - thank you, solution is `df=df1[['CLOSDATE_year','LCR','WFR']].copy()` - If you modify values in df later you will find that the modifications do not propagate back to the original data (df1), and that Pandas does warning.